# Why is it <T> Matcher<T> as return type in Hamcrest instanceOf method

Tags: java, generics, hamcrest

I am having trouble understanding the method signature of the 'instanceOf' method in hamcrest package. Here is the method

```
public static <T> Matcher<T> instanceOf(Class<?> type) {
    return (Matcher<T>) new IsInstanceOf(type);
}
```

I can understand the return type is Matcher`<T>` and first `<T>` declares generic. But `T` is never inferred in the method. Notice we don't pass `T` as argument type.

One question arises: does it mean `T` is unbounded and we can dynamically cast return Matcher to any type?

Comment: It means you can call this method in any context that expects a `Matcher<anything>` without needing to cast.

Comment: could you provide an example. and does `anything` mean wildcard in the case?

Comment: "Anything" means any specific type parameter or wildcard (bounded or unbounded).  The value of the type argument can be inferred from the context of the method invocation, for almost any context.  It is also possible, and in rare cases may be necessary, to specify the type argument explicitly: `IsInstanceOf.<CharSequence>instanceOf(String.class)`.

Comment: Thank you. Your comment helps me to locate the tutorial on oracle docs that explains in details.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html   Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The `Matcher` type that `instanceOf` returns is not really useful until you actually... well, use it.

And yes, you can assign the resulting `Matcher` to any type.

For example, you can do this:

```
// <T> is inferred to be 'Object' here
Matcher<Object> objectMatcher = instanceOf(Integer.class);
```

or this

```
// <T> is inferred to be 'Integer' here
Matcher<Integer> integerMatcher = instanceOf(Integer.class);
```

and try to use the `Matcher`s with `assertThat` in these ways:

```
// succeeds and expectedly so
// Integer.class.isInstance(5) is true
assertThat(5, objectMatcher);

// succeeds and expectedly so 
// Integer.class.isInstance(5) is true
assertThat(5, integerMatcher);

// fails, but only after asserting, by throwing an AssertionError at runtime
// Integer.class.isInstance(Double) is false; 
// but we wouldn't have gotten this far had we used the right matcher
assertThat(5.5d, objectMatcher);

 // fails at compile time; exactly what we want generics to offer us - compile time safety
assertThat(5.5d, integerMatcher);

// you can also do it this way 
// if you wanted to force T instead of 
// expecting the compiler to infer it for you based on the context
assertThat(5, IsInstanceOf.<Integer>instanceOf(Integer.class));
```

Compare these invocations with the signature of `assertThat` to understand what `T` (a different `T` from the one used with `instanceOf`!) and `? super T` would be in each case:

```
public static <T> void assertThat(T actual, Matcher<? super T> matcher)


// actual would be Integer and matcher would be Matcher<Object>
assertThat(5, objectMatcher);

// actual would be Integer and matcher would be Matcher<Integer>
assertThat(5, integerMatcher);

// actual would be Double and matcher would be Matcher<Object>
assertThat(5.5d, objectMatcher);

// actual would be Double and matcher would be Matcher<Integer>; see the mismatch?
assertThat(5.5d, integerMatcher);
```

Comment: Did you mean `Matcher<Integer> objectMatcher = instanceOf(Integer.class);` to be `Matcher<Object> objectMatcher = instanceOf(Object.class);`?

Comment: @DavidHarkness, well I really meant to write `Matcher<Object> objectMatcher = instanceOf(Integer.class);` to show how the two different `Matcher` types affect the outcome and of course back up my statement: "_And yes, you can assign the resulting Matcher to any type._". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to this question is simple. Since the type parameter `T` is not used in any of the parameters of the `instanceOf` method, the compiler is allowed to infer *any type* to use as a type argument for that method call. Therefore, the compiler can always infer a type that "works" in the context of the method call (simply speaking).

This all just means that a line like

```
assertThat(something, instanceOf(Some.class));
```

will always type check, no matter the static type of `something`, because the compiler will infer `T` to be the static type of `something`, both for the `assertThat` and for the `instanceOf` call.

And this is a good thing, because the whole point of the line is to check the *dynamic* type of `something`, which is not statically known. If the precise type of `something` were statically known, this assertion would not even be necessary.